# Flatness of a manifold (or a connection)

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Suppose we have an $n$-dimensional manifold $S$ (with a global coordinate system) with a metric $g$ and a connection $\nabla$ with connection coefficients (Christoffel symbols) $\Gamma_{i,j}^k$ given. Suppose that the $\nabla$-geodesic connecting any two points of the manifold completely lies in $S$. Can we then say that $S$ must be flat with respect to the given connection? I am not able to straightaway show that $(\Gamma_{i,j}^k)_p = 0$ at all points $p$ of $S$.

Comment: No. One counter example is the Poincare disk. It is topologically the unit disc in $\mathbb R^2$ equipped with a metric of negative curvature.

Comment: @John: Can you elaborate a bit on what is curvature and so on?

Comment: What do you mean by flat?

Comment: @John: I got it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are misunderstanding what a flat (affine) connection is: It is a connection on a manifold $M$ such that at each point of $M$ there exists a coordinate system with zero Christoffel symbols (vanishing depends heavily on which coordinates you use). Equivalently, a connection is flat if it has zero curvature. Equivalently, it is flat if parallel transports  along contractible loops are identity maps, etc. This will be explained in any Riemannian geometry textbook; my favorite is do Carmo's "Riemannian Geometry" (chapters 0 through 4). Or use Petersen's "Riemannian Geometry".

Comment: Thank you very much for the references.